# error Append lista Python

Tags: python

Tengo que resolver esto:

> Paso 1: Crea una lista vacía llamada beatles.
> Paso 2: Emplea el método append() para agregar los siguientes miembros de
> la banda a la lista: John Lennon, Paul McCartney y George Harrison.
> Paso 3: Emplea el ciclofor y el append() para pedirle al usuario que agregue los siguientes miembros de la banda a la lista: Stu Sutcliffe, y Pete Best.
> Paso 4: Usa la instrucción del para eliminar a Stu Sutcliffe y Pete Best de
> la lista.
> Paso 5: Usa el método insert() para agregar a Ringo Starr al principio de la lista.

Cuando escribo los `del` para borrar los nombres, me sale un error. ¿Alguien sabe por qué y cómo lo puedo solucionar?

```
    beatles = []
beatles.append(["John Lennon","Paul McCartney", "George Harrison"])

print(beatles)

for x in range (2):
    Cantante = input("Ingrese el nombre del cantante: ")
    beatles.append(Cantante)

print(beatles)

del beatles[1]
del beatles[2]

print(beatles)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como no entiendo ?

Comment: Perdón me había equivocado >_<

Comment: El error es de lógica. Si tu eliminas el segundo elemento de tu lista que tiene solo 3 elementos, entonces ahora solo tienes 2 elementos y los índices en python van del 0 al n-1 por lo que en una lista de 2 elementos no existe el índice 2 y ese es tu error

Comment: Lectura recomendada: [por qué se debe agregar el mensaje de error como texto y no como imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Además, dale un título descriptivo a tu pregunta: _error Append lista Python_ no da pistas del error en cuestión. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

a la a hora de introducir los miembros los has echo como una lista a una lista, quedando una lista de lista y claro luego al incluir los otros dos cantantes sonó tiene índice cero e índice 1. Deberías haber introducido los músicos dentro de la lista como elementos independientes, luego a la hora de eliminarlos si lo haces eliminando del( longitud de la lista -1) eliminas el último elemento que son los que has introducido más tarde. Quedaría algo así: por cierto intenta con dar nombres de variables en mayúsculas simplemente por convención, s una buena práctica.

```
beatles = []
miembros=["John Lennon","Paul McCartney", "George Harrison"]
for musico in miembros:
  beatles.append(musico)
print(beatles)
for x in range (2):
  cantante = input("Ingrese el nombre del cantante: ")
  beatles.append(cantante)  
print(beatles)
del beatles[len(beatles)-1]
del beatles[len(beatles)-1]
print(beatles)
```

Comment: no hace falta usar un ciclo `for` basta con `beatles.extend(mienbros)`

Comment: también sería conveniente usar el método `remove` para eliminar el elemento